# Two timeouts interrupt with each other

Tags: javascript

So I tried adding a slideshow with setTimeout, but after adding it other function stopped working. I tried changing setTimeout to setInterval, but also it didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
    window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        let x = document.querySelector('.loaderWrap')
        x.remove();
    }, 1500)
}

let i = 0;
let images = [];


images[0] = ''
images[1] = ''
images[2] = ''

 function changeImage() {  
    document.slide.src = images[i];
    if(i<images.length - 1){
        i++;
    }else{
        i=0;
    }
    setTimeout('changeImage()', 1000);
    document.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function () {
        if(i>0){
            i--;
        }
    }
}window.onload = changeImage;
```

Comment: [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) is a function that takes a timeout id as a parameter. The timeout id is returned by [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) (whose overload taking a string is not recommended).

Comment: Also note that by using `window.onload = ` you are overwriting the onload handler. Use `addEventListener('load', function() { .... })` to add event listeners non-destructively.

Comment: I tried experimenting with clearTimeout and I have forgotten to remove it, edited post.

Comment: What is `.loaderWrap`? Can you create a runnable snippet that reproduces the issues you have? (Use the toolbar)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript event window.onload not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810825/javascript-event-window-onload-not-triggered)

Comment: @trincot LoaderWrap is my styling for loading animation and after that specified time (1500) that element is removed.

Comment: But you said (in the title) the timeouts interfered. How? Does it concern that one? Can you edit your question and turn it into a runnable snippet, demonstrating the malfunctioning?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. I just used addEventListener as @HereticMonkey told and it works great, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `window.onload` multiple times, it'll override the previous value when you use it again, and will only execute the last function you assign to it. As a fix to that, you can use `window.addEventListener('load', function(){})` this will allow you to stack as many event listeners as you need for the same element even if they are the same event type.

When using `setTimeout()` when passing a string javascript will automatically pass it to `eval()` and it will work, but in your case, you don't need to do that. you can simply pass the name of the function as an argument.

Instead of: `setTimeout('changeImage()', 1000)`
Do: `setTimeout(changeImage, 1000)`

Your final code after refactoring will look something like:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    let x = document.querySelector('.loaderWrap');
    x.remove();
  }, 1500);
});

let i = 0;
let images = [];

images[0] = '';
images[1] = '';
images[2] = '';

function changeImage() {
  document.slide.src = images[i]
  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  setTimeout(changeImage, 1000)
  document.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function () {
    if (i > 0) {
      i--;
    }
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', changeImage);
```