# Page Pre loader not removing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me why the pre loader div doesn't disappear after the page is loaded and specified added time. It used to work, now it doesn't on a new site... I think I may have missed something when using it on the new site.

it just shows the div and stays on that screen forever.

```js
$('body').append('<div id="loading-container"><div id="loading-inner"><p id="percent">100</p><div id="bar"><div id="bar-percent"></div></div></div></div>');

$(window).on('load', function(){
  setTimeout(removeLoader, 2750); //wait for page load PLUS x.
});

function removeLoader(){
    //fadeUp.play();
    $( "#loading-container" ).fadeOut(250, function() {
      // fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
      $( "#loading-container" ).remove(); //makes page more lightweight 
    });  
}
```

```css
/* LOADER */
#loading-container {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: #131313;
  z-index: 20;
}
#loading-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#percent {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-family: canela
}
#bar {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #424242;
  height: 1px;
  align-self: center;
}
#bar-percent {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works fine in your snippet, except for `fadeUp` not being defined. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810825/javascript-event-window-onload-not-triggered) for your actual code.

Comment: It works well for me. If it isn't working in your site then see the **console** for any **error**, because it may caused by any other code that stops executing the code before loader div disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code. i jsut save html string with jquery object in loader variable. and now its not depend on id.

```
var loader = $('<div id="loading-container"><div id="loading-inner"><p id="percent">100</p><div id="bar"><div id="bar-percent"></div></div></div></div>')

$('body').append(loader);

$(window).on('load', function(){
  setTimeout(removeLoader, 2750); //wait for page load PLUS x.
});

function removeLoader(){
    //fadeUp.play();
    loader.fadeOut(250, function() {
      // fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
      loader.remove(); //makes page more lightweight 
    });  
}
```