# Random image load works fine offline, but not on website

Tags: javascript, image, random, onload

This code works perfectly fine by itself but as soon as I embed it into a website it no longer loads an image on page load. Why? How can it be improved?

My guess is the susceptible `windowon.load`. Maybe it can be substituted?

```js
//$(document).ready(function(){choosePic;}
//alert(window.onload);
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810825/javascript-event-window-onload-not-triggered;
window.onload = choosePic;
var onloadd = window.onload;
var myPix = new Array(
  "https://m.box.com/file/903146245504/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fj7i88s6jb4yyk4wmiti4tol8ejoikdhl/preview/preview.png",
  "https://m.box.com/file/1055524661946/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fj7i88s6jb4yyk4wmiti4tol8ejoikdhl/preview/preview.png",
  "https://m.box.com/file/896387464705/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fj7i88s6jb4yyk4wmiti4tol8ejoikdhl/preview/preview.png"
);

function choosePic() {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
  document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
  ('#myPicture').html(` ${myPicture} `);
  ('#today').html(` ${onloadd} `);
}
```

```html
<button id=onloadd></button>
<button id="myrdpbtn" style="background:transparent; border:transparent;" onclick="choosePic()">RandomPicture</button>
<button id=onloadd></button><br>

<img src="https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/release/0mine/documents/art/empty.png" width=1000 id="myPicture"><br><br>
```

Comment: It seems, it loads *slower* while on site. Is there a way to speed up the first load ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
<!----RandomImage--->
<button id="myrdpbtn" style="background:transparent; border:transparent;" onclick="swap()">RandomPicture</button>
<style type="text/css">
#banner {height:100%;object-fit: contain;
//padding:0;margin:0;text-align:right;
//position:relative;
//position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 1200px;
//background-position: center center;
background-size: contain; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if (document.getElementById) { window.onload = swap };
function swap() {
var numimages=8;
rndimg = new Array(
"https://m.box.com/file/903146245504/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fj7i88s6jb4yyk4wmiti4tol8ejoikdhl/preview/preview.png",
"https://m.box.com/file/905690094898/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fj7i88s6jb4yyk4wmiti4tol8ejoikdhl/preview/preview.png",
"https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/055/144/127/large/ryedai1-2022-10-19-aoi-realist-no2.jpg?1666212593",
"https://other00.deviantart.net/c476/o/2021/321/8/f/subaru_and_misora_by_pasc91.png",
"https://m.box.com/file/900365515983/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fj7i88s6jb4yyk4wmiti4tol8ejoikdhl/preview/preview.png",
"https://m.box.com/file/889506897379/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fj7i88s6jb4yyk4wmiti4tol8ejoikdhl/preview/preview.png",
"https://m.box.com/file/903146245504/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fj7i88s6jb4yyk4wmiti4tol8ejoikdhl/preview/preview.png",


"https://m.box.com/file/896387464705/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fj7i88s6jb4yyk4wmiti4tol8ejoikdhl/preview/preview.png"
); 
x=(Math.floor(Math.random()*numimages));
randomimage=(rndimg[x]);
document.getElementById("banner").style.backgroundImage = "url("+ randomimage +")"; 
}</script>
</head>
<div id="banner""></div>
```